# How to update a node version in React App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, upgrade

We have a react app that uses 14.x.x version. Now we would like to upgrade the node version to 19.x.x. Can you please guide the steps to do that?

In package.json it is mentioned as

```
engines: {
    "node": ">=14.15.1"
}
```

Comment: well basically engines section is just advisory and not connected to react. React uses the installed version when you run npm run

Answer (score 1):

its `npm update` is the command to update all dependencies in the project but first check the outdated packages and comparisons using `npm outdated` command. it will nicely list the current, outdated and required package list.
[image]
check the list and update as per your project code.
https://docs.npmjs.com/updating-packages-downloaded-from-the-registry

Answer (score 0):

Using NPM:To update Node using NPM do the following:
1.Open the Terminal and check your current Node version:  node -v 
Install n package using the following command:
npm install -g n

This command will install a tool called "n" which you can use to update Node easily.

2.To update Node, run the following command in your terminal:           
n latest
This command will install the latest version of Node on your system.Now you can

3.verify that your update is complete by rechecking your Node version:  
node -v.

You can also manually download and install the latest Node version from the official website.
https://nodejs.org/en/download/current

Comment: This gives me steps to upgrade node in my machine. But how to make react to use that node version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can run the command `npm update` or `npm update --save` or `npm update --save-dev`, depending on your needs